# when moving from https page to http page cookies has been deleted in IE

Tags: java, internet-explorer, spring-mvc, spring-security

**I tried to moving from https page to http page cookies has been deleted in IE**

Browser it replicate:
**Internet Explorer**

I am working on java based commerce suite.

Step that I have done:

When I have logged in https page and moves to http page,the cookies and sessions has been cleared,the user has been logged off

It was replicated only in IE